# Why is the smallest number read from my file always 0? (Java)

Tags: java, file, random, file-io

When I run the program, the smallest number **always** turns out to be 0. Why is this? The largest and average values seem to be correct.

The problem most likely lies in how I am using the random class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReadAndWrite {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int i_data = 0;
    int[] sort = new int[100];
    File file = new File("Test4");
    int total = 0;
    int average = 0;    

    try {
    file.createNewFile();
    }       
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not create the file for some reason. Try again.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Test4");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
          int x = ran.nextInt(100);
          oos.writeInt(x);
        }
        oos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Whoops");
    }

    try {           
        FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream("Test4");
        ObjectInputStream ooss = new ObjectInputStream(fos);            

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sort[i] = ooss.readInt();

        }
        Arrays.sort(sort);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            total = total + sort[i];
            average = total/100;
        }


        System.out.println("The largest number in the file is: " + sort[99]);
        System.out.println("The smallest number in the file is: " + sort[0]);
        System.out.println("The average number in the file is: " + average);

        ooss.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you always sort after addint one more number?

Comment: why you are calling `Arrays.sort()` 100 times. may be chance of getting `0` also because of `nextInt(100)`.

Comment: Okay I have ran the program a multitude of times and I have finally got a 1 as my smallest value. @Satya Thank you for pointing that out. I put Arrays.sort() in the loop by mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sorting the array as you read each value.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     sort[i] = ooss.readInt();
     Arrays.sort(sort);
 }
```

This means you start with [1, 0, 0, 0, ...] but after sorting you have [0, 0, 0, ... 1 ]

This is where a debugger would help you debug your program.  The solution is to only sort the array after you have read it.

A simpler solution is to write and read the array in one go instead of using a loop.

BTW: Unless you are writing/reading objects you don'#t need to be using ObjectOutputStream and it has an overhead compared with say DataOutputStream.

As @KevinEsche points out, if you have 100 random values of 0 to 99 there is a good chance that one of them will be 0, though not every time.

A shorter implementation could look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Random rand = new Random();

    int samples = 100;
    try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test"))) {
        out.writeInt(samples);
        for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
            out.writeInt(rand.nextInt(100));
    }

    int[] sort;
    try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("test"))) {
        int len = in.readInt();
        sort = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            sort[i] = in.readInt();
    }

    IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(sort).summaryStatistics();
    System.out.println("The largest number in the file is: " + stats.getMax());
    System.out.println("The smallest number in the file is: " + stats.getMin());
    System.out.println("The average number in the file is: " + stats.getAverage());
}
```

Comment: i´d add with the current implementation with the `Random` it´s still pretty likely that this is about to be `0` as smallest number

Comment: @Thomas half the values will end up being 0 so that is a big difference.

Comment: Hmm, I misunderstood your answer. You're right, after sorting for the first time element 0 will have the value 0 and he's going to read the next value into element 1 effectively overwriting half of the values.